# MySQL - change all tables' ENGINE from MyISAM to InnoDB with a single query

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I had some foreign key issues in my database when I change the table engine "**`MyISAM`**" to "**`InnoDB`**" but then it works fine.

I found one query to change a single table's engine but I have many tables so what I want to know is there any way to do it all once?

#### ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENGINE=INNODB;

What else I have tried?

I also tried to update the **my.ini** file by adding the code below but it doesn't work!

#### default-storage-engine = InnoDB

I found a query way is more convenient as of my understanding so any suggestion for a change it all table engine at once?

This is the Database server detail:

```
Server: 13227.3232.3232.3232 via TCP/IP
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.4.10-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10
```

Answer (score 4):

My strong advice is not to try and do this on a running database! `MyISAM` isn't transactional in any case, so any operation that spans many tables can't be performed in this manner (it can in `InnoDB` - your reason for wanting to change?). You will have to either dump the db and modify the text file **or** iterate through the tables.

MySQL is moving firmly **away** from `MyISAM` - it's being [deprecated](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/10/11/mysql-8-0-end-myisam/). Not even the system tables are `MyISAM` anymore (MySQL >= 8.xx).

BTW, please **always** include the **version** of MySQL that you are using - it can be **very** important - see below!

Therefore, I propose the following solution:

### Step 1:

Take a backup of your database using `mysqldump` - you should be doing this on a regular basis anyway - [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-back-up-and-restore-mysql-databases-with-mysqldump/) is a reference (there are many!):

```
mysqldump database_name > database_name.sql
```

of if you have multiple databases on the same server:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --databases database_name_a database_name_b ... > databases_a_b.sql
```

### Step 2:

Using the text editor of your choice, go through the file and search for the word `ENGINE` and replace each occurrence of `ENGINE=MyISAM` with `ENGINE=InnoDB`.

If you're on `*nix`, then something like this will do the trick:

```
sed -e 's/ENGINE=MyISAM/ENGINE=InnoDB/g' > new_file.sql
```

Do **not** do this for every occurrence of `MyISAM` in the entire MySQL server! If you are using a version of MySQL which still has `MyISAM` system tables - this is very risky - from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/system-schema.html) - MySQL 5.7. Will not apply for later versions which have moved the system tables to `InnoDB` anyway:

> Warning Do not convert MySQL system tables in the mysql database from
>   MyISAM to InnoDB tables. This is an unsupported operation. If you do
>   this, MySQL does not restart until you restore the old system tables
>   from a backup or regenerate them by reinitializing the data directory
>   (see Section 2.10.1, “Initializing the Data Directory”).

So, do **not** do the change for any tables in the `mysql`, `information_schema` or `performance_schema` databases - only in the databases that you've created yourself.

### Step 3:

Restore from this backup and you're good to go! You should drop your original database and recreate an empty schema (see reference above) of the same name and then:

```
mysqld  database_name < new_file.sql
```

At this point, you may wish to implement `FOREIGN KEYS` - one of the **many** good reasons to upgrade to `InnoDB`! Be careful - `MyISAM` doesn't have DRI ([`Declarative Referential Integrity`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity)) so there may be orphaned records in your existing system - you might want to run tests to check on this?

### Running system alternative:

If you're unable to bring down the database, then a solution like this (iterating through every table in the schema) might be helpful (adapted from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html#innodb-convert-convert) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37314063/470530)):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTables ()
BEGIN
  DECLARE Finished BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE TableName VARCHAR(64);

  DECLARE TablesCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT c1.TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1
    WHERE c1.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_schema';

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET Finished = TRUE;

  OPEN TablesCursor;

  MainLoop: LOOP
    FETCH TablesCursor INTO TableName;
    IF Finished THEN
      LEAVE MainLoop;
    END IF;

    SET @queryText = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TableName , ' ENGINE=InnoDB');  -- may or may not need backtics
    PREPARE updateQuery FROM @queryText;
    EXECUTE updateQuery;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE updateQuery;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE TablesCursor;
END
```

Note: this is **untested** - please use with caution and do your own tests before committing to a definitive solution. I would also advise doing something like this when the system load is as light as possible!

### Alternatives to the alternative (again, not tested):

If you're a PHP person, [this](https://gist.github.com/michael-e/5789168) might be suitable.

Another (interesting) approach is [this one](https://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/mysql-foreach) by Shlomi Noach - a [big hitter](https://il.linkedin.com/in/shlominoach) in the MySQL world.

Answer (score 2):

Since your real goal is to convert MyISAM to InnoDB, there are other issues that *may* need dealing with.

I cover all the issues in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb , including how to run a single SQL to generate the set of `ALTERs` that you are asking for.