# What MariaDB storage engine should i use?

Tags: mariadb, storage-engine

I have a database with size about 170GB with rows between 20.000 - 700.000.000 rows (depending on the table). Currently i'm using MyISAM storage engine.

In my case, querying (READ) speed is very important, but transactional is optional.

My CRUD Operation estimates is :

- 98% READ
- 2% INSERT
- < 1% for both UPDATE & DELETE

Comment: Are the inserts by appending an Auto_increment table (because there are table-lock free rather than other PK based insert)? Keep in mind innodb will need to be tuned its innodb_buffer_pool_size if you deside to transition. Any particular mariadb version?

Comment: No, the primary key isn't from AUTO INCREAMENT. I haven't checked my MariaDB, but it should be latest version since the OS is rolling release.

Comment: @ilos-vigil - Elaborate on what you mean by that comment on `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Show us a `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only real choice here is between `InnoDB` and Percona's [`XtraDB`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/percona_xtradb.html) engines - see [this page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/storage-engines/).

Coincidentally, I wrote an answer to [Change all table ENGINE at once from "MyISAM" to "InnoDB" in MySql with single query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/261942) this morning on how to convert from `MyISAM` to `InnoDB` which might be of interest to you? There are very good reasons for not going with anything non-transactional!

> Any particular reason you recommend InnoDB/XtraDB since [MariaDB blog](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/storage-engine-choice-aria/) recommend Aria instead?

Yes - for their transactional capabilities - you get DRI ([`Declarative Referential Integrity`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity)) thrown in. Enforcing DRI app-side is a disaster waiting to happen - whereas if you use the RDBMS, you have a system that's been tested by literally **millions** of people. If you "roll-your-own", you have to rewrite it every time you want to write a new app for that particular schema - and if your data is important, this **will** happen! I would **urge** you to use either InnoDB or XtraDB but if you **do** insist on an NTE, then go with Aria! -  [Vérace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34007/v%C3%A9race)

Comment: btw XtraDB was removed in 10.3. The NTE is "Near Term Extinction" yes?

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB, period, fullstop.  One caution:  The disk space will increase by between 2x and 3x.

This discusses the various things you need to watch out for:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb .  And it provides the desired `ALTERs`.

Do change the settings.  Most importantly is to decrease `key_buffer_size` and increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  (See my link.)

"Read speed" -- Oracle has been "proving" for the last few releases that InnoDB is faster.  Because of the "clustering" of the PK in InnoDB, it *may* be better to make a few changes to the indexes (primary and secondary).